# Download multiple XML files

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm writing an application to parse XML. I have to obtain data from one XML file, and then in a loop I have to open another XML file.

The code looks like this:

```
$doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('myxmladress'))
$doc.xpath('//job').each do |job|
  if job.xpath('name').text.include?('joe')
    $doc2 = Nokogiri::XML(open('myxmladress_for_joe'))
  end
end
```

I believe that I cannot have multiple HTTP connections open.

Can I simply download the whole file instead of using

```
$doc Nokogiri::XML(open('myxmladress'))
```

or is there any way to close the Nokogiri HTTP connection?

What is more I'm downloading it by https.

My error:

```
in `open_http': 500 Server Error (OpenURI::HTTPError)
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:737:in `buffer_open'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
from jenkins_auth.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in combine_partial_results'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
from jenkins_auth.rb:89:in `block in combine_partial_results'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
from /home/nagios/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
from jenkins_auth.rb:86:in `combine_partial_results'
from jenkins_auth.rb:130:in `get_tests_for_job'
from jenkins_auth.rb:137:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe Nokogiri takes care of this stuff of multiple http connections inside it and you don't need to care about this. Is your code running? If not, what are the error messages?

Comment: The error is on the server side: 500 error code means the server had an internal error.

Comment: So to sum it all up, the problem is probably with server and I my method of doing it as shown in the code above is mjore or less correct?

Comment: It looks reasonable. Just to make sure though, when you are assigning $doc2, you are opening a different document, right?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida, Nokogiri has no idea of HTTP connections at all. It only reads a stream, or takes a string, and parses it.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using OpenUri to fetch a document from a URL. I am pretty sure that this doesn't leave any open connection, but reads the document into an IO like object, kind of like a file.

Your problem seems to be that the server has had an internal error.

Comment: OpenURI returns a StringIO object if I remember right.